# Delete all messages of facebook on one go

Tags: facebook

how i may delete all the messages of face book on one go note that i am using latest version of Facebook with timelines option on 
once i done this with the help of crome addon but now that add on is not working due to some changes in facebook message page .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There is no SDK function call to do so.